# Someone who knows CanvasRenderingContext2D in React, please help :)

Tags: reactjs

When I click on the spin button, I want the value to be highlighted one by one in the canvas.
Here you can see the whole code: https://codesandbox.io/s/spinning-wheel-react-forked-s528m

```
  renderWheel() {
    // determine number/size of sectors that need to created
    let numOptions = this.state.list.length;
    let arcSize = (2 * Math.PI) / numOptions;
    this.setState({
      angle: arcSize
    });

    // dynamically generate sectors from state list
    let angle = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < numOptions; i++) {
      let text = this.state.list[i];
      this.renderSector(i + 1, text, angle, arcSize);
      angle += arcSize;
    }
  }

  renderSector(index, text, start, arc) {
    // create canvas arc for each list element
    let canvas = document.getElementById("wheel");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let x = canvas.width / 2;
    let y = canvas.height / 2;
    let radius = 200;
    let startAngle = start;
    let endAngle = start + arc - 0.02;
    let angle = index * arc;
    let baseSize = radius * 1.25;
    let textRadius = baseSize - 48;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
    ctx.lineWidth = radius * 0.25;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";

    ctx.font = "25px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";

    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(
      baseSize + Math.cos(angle - arc / 2) * textRadius,
      baseSize + Math.sin(angle - arc / 2) * textRadius
    );
    ctx.rotate(0);
    ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 7);
    ctx.restore();
  }
```

When I click on the spin button, this spin () method is executed.
The iteration ends between two and five seconds as written in the setTimeout method.

```
spin = () => {
    var index = 0;
    let timer = setInterval(() => {
      index = (index) % this.state.list.length + 1;
      console.log(index)
    }, 150);
  
    // calcalute result after wheel stops spinning
    setTimeout(() => {
     clearInterval(timer);

      this.setState({
        hasFinishedLoading: true,
        display: this.state.list[index]
      });
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000 + 2000));

    this.setState({
      spinning: true
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember: In canvas you cannot access a particular object, so the solution is always to erase and redraw. Don't worry about performance, this is pretty great. I leave you an idea with your code and at the end some suggestions. Try this code, the only thing I did is clean the canvas and redraw without the setTimeOut index

```
spin = () => {
  let canvas = document.getElementById("wheel");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var index = 0;
  index = (index % this.state.list.length) + 1;
  let angle = 0;
  let numOptions = this.state.list.length;
  let arcSize = (2 * Math.PI) / numOptions;
  let timer = setInterval(() => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  this.setState({
    angle: arcSize
  });
  for (let i = 0; i < numOptions; i++) {
    if (i !== index) {
      let text = this.state.list[i];
      this.renderSector(i + 1, text, angle, arcSize);
      angle += arcSize;
    } else {
    }
  }
}, 150);

// calcalute result after wheel stops spinning
setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(timer);

  this.setState({
    hasFinishedLoading: true,
    display: this.state.list[index]
  });
}, Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000 + 2000));

this.setState({
  spinning: true
});
};
```

- Don't use "getElementById" in react, it's dangerous. Use a reference.

Comment: Thank you very much. But is there any way to prevent values from being erased? That really matters to me

Comment: @Alex To generate the effect of change on a canvas, you must clean and redraw. In this case you must clean the entire canvas, draw the wheel except the position in which it goes, and in that position draw with another color or size.

Comment: I understand. Do you think I can make the same wheel in a much better way without CanvasRenderingContext2D? Some suggestions

Comment: @Alex You could also use divs and css (properties transform, rotate, etc). Anyway I think that the most optimal is canvas.

Comment: Hey, I managed to make the values visible while rendering. You can take a look here if you are interested: https://codesandbox.io/s/spinning-wheel-react-forked-s528m

Comment: Can you give me some suggestions on how to place the images instead of the text that is now on the canvas? And set the path to the image for the property?

Comment: @Alex By community rules it is best to move this conversation to chat. I'll be checking. It may take a few hours to reply

Comment: I sent you an email